# Why does Python believe return_value is a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is wrong with the following bit of code?

```
class Dice:
    def roll_dice(x):
        import random
        return_value = '('
        try:
            y = int(x)
        except ValueError:
            return None
        for char in range(y):
            return_value += f'{random.randint(1, 6)}, '
        return_value = list(return_value).remove[-1 and -2]
        return_value = ''.join(str(e) for e in return_value)
        return return_value + ')'

parameter = input('Number of dice rolls: ')
print(Dice.roll_dice(parameter))
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MyName/PycharmProjects/ProjectName/filename.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(Dice.roll_dice(parameter))
  File "C:/Users/MyName/PycharmProjects/ProjectName/filename.py", line 11, in roll_dice
    return_value = list(return_value).remove[-1 and -2]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

If I understand Python correctly, it thinks `return_value` is a string. But didn't I take the list of `return_value` on line 11 where the problem is? How does that work?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `remove[-1 and -2]`. `remove` is a method, so it must be followed by parentheses, not brackets. That's what *not subscriptable* means.

Also, `-1 and -2` does not do what you think it does, apply `remove(-1)` and `remove(-2)` separately.

Comment: @oPtImUz: they are not the same, `pop` removes by position, `remove` removes by vaiue. If you just want all the elements except the last two, you can use `my_list[:-2]`

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of a class method should be named `self`, but the class is not a real class, because this missing `self` is never used. Write it as a normal function.
`import` belongs to the beginning of the file, not inside functions.
Instead of building a string with extra `,` and removing it by converting it to a list and back again to a string, you could simply use

```
return_value = return_value[:-2]
```

but it would be better to not create a string in first place, but a list:

```
import random

def roll_dice(x):
    try:
        y = int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return None
    values = []
    for _ in range(y):
        values.append(str(random.randint(1, 6)))
    return f'({", ".join(values)})'
```